# Rust wasm: How to wait for Future to resolve

Tags: asynchronous, rust, webassembly

I have the following WASM code with the asynchronous function `request_data` that performs an asynchronous call to an arbitrary API and logs the resolved Promise to the console. To check for orchestration, I am logging before and after I execute this function. Naturally, when I am not specifying to wait for the asynchronous function, its output will be logged after my surrounding logs:

```rust
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen(inline_js = "export async function request_data() { console.log(await <some_async_call>) }")]
extern {
    pub async fn request_data();
}

#[wasm_bindgen(inline_js = "export function log(text) { console.log(text) }")]
extern {
    pub fn log(text: &str);
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn main() {
    log("Before");
    request_data();
    log("After");
}
```

When I run function `main`, I am getting the following output to the console:

```
Before
After
<async call result data>
```

What I want to achieve is to let the `main` function wait until the Future resolves, before it is logging `"After"`. I tried the following, but it just endlessly wait for the Future to resolve:

```rust
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use futures::executor::*;

#[wasm_bindgen(inline_js = "export async function request_data() { console.log(await <some_async_call>) }")]
extern {
    pub async fn request_data();
}

#[wasm_bindgen(inline_js = "export function log(text) { console.log(text) }")]
extern {
    pub fn log(text: &str);
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn main() {
    log("Before");
    block_on(request_data());
    log("After");
}
```

This just leads to this output

```
Before
```

So my question is, how I can orchestrate the `main` function to get the following output:

```
Before
<async call result data>
After
```

Comment: You can't block the main thread in the browser. Period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the calling function async too:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub async fn main() {
    log("Before");
    request_data().await;
    log("After");
}
```

When this function is exported to JavaScript, it will become a function returning a `Promise`, just like a JS async function. That's all you need to do, usually.

---

From the perspective of Rust async, the browser provides an already-existing, single-threaded async executor. You should not use any other async executor within it. The [`wasm-bindgen-futures`](https://docs.rs/wasm-bindgen-futures/latest/wasm_bindgen_futures/) library provides API for explicitly working with promises and futures if you need to.